# discord.py добавить проверку на ботов sqlite3

Tags: python, discord, sqlite3, discord.py

Хочу сделать так чтобы при отправке команды мне показывало список юзеров и их деньги, но такое я уже сделал, но вот проблема, там ещё показывает и ботов а мне нужно чтобы их не показывало, я искал в интернете не нашел.
вот код:

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['топ', 'лидеры', 'top'])
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title = "Топ 5 плэйбоев", color = disnake.Color.purple())
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT id, cash FROM users WHERE guild_id = ? ORDER BY cash DESC LIMIT 5", (ctx.guild.id,)):
await bot.fetch_user(id) 
if user.bot:
    continue
    counter += 1
    embed.add_field(
        name = f"# {counter} | `{bot.get_user(row[0])}` | Денег: {row[1]} ₽",
        value = f"—————————————————————————"
        )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожертвуйте парой дополнительных строк и сделайте проверку на ботов:

```py
user = bot.get_user(row[0])

# если пользователь - бот, то свойство bot вернет True
if user.bot:
    # пропускаем дальнейшие действия в цикле
    # и сразу же переходим на следующую итерацию
    continue

counter += 1
embed.add_field(
    name = f"# {counter} | `{user}` | Денег: {row[1]} ₽",
    value = f"—————————————————————————"
)
```

Comment: error:```if user.bot:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'```

Comment: Что-то непонятно в тексте ошибки? Это значит объект `user` принял значение `None`, то есть не удалось получить пользователя через `bot.get_user()`. Ну, можете использовать `await bot.fetch_user(id)`

Comment: опять ошибка```In user_id: Value "<built-in function id>" is not snowflake.```

Comment: обновите код в вопросе на актуальный, что-то я даже не представляю что вы там делаете, что у вас такая ошибка

Comment: @Timur отступы-то выровняйте

Comment: я расставил табуляцию, это так в вопросе получилось плохо

Comment: В таком случае я не представляю с чем связана ошибка. У меня этот код работает, да и ошибка связана не с кодом из ответа. Могу помочь, только если загрузите полный код (без токена) на https://pastebin.com/

Comment: можете написать мне в дискорд:
*➜ ᴛɪᴍᴜʀ#0530*